# Coax Cable Shorted in Home - Trying to Add MOCA (Cox cable/internet)

Tags: coaxial-cable, internet

I've successfully added 3 MOCA adapters to my cox internet setup (cable tv + cable internet).

I identified the coax cables I want to use for hard wiring except 1 - which is shorted. By process of elimination - that is likely the one to the room where I want to put a hard wire to improve online meetings.

What do you recommend on how to identify where a shorted coax cable is shorted and fixing it? I guess dragging my sorry self into the attic is a possibility.

Details:

- Incoming cable with POE filter
- COX splitter is a 3 way (Downstairs office / main internet room / television or "TV" in family room)
- 3 unconnected cables - 2 "open" and 1 short. 1 of those cables identified as the master bedroom. One is likely in a storage room where the cable is inaccessible. 1 should be the office location.

Thanks.

Comment: BTW - added another MOCA splitter to add the master; tried changing the splitter but the tv started having bad dropouts. So it's a splitter off a splitter - which works fine so far.

Comment: For large installation, *time domain reflectometry,* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-domain_reflectometer, is used. Glad you realized that device input can read as short circuit, since a time domain reflectometer is an expensive bit of kit, unless you have a very friendly and trusting IT staffer to loan one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The splitters will typically show a short when using an ohmmeter. In the CATV industry, 75 ohm resistors integrated in a threaded cap are used to identify specific cable runs, as the capped line will read 75 ohms while others will read open or shorted by splitter.

Ensure that the lines you are examining do not have splitters in the circuit or other devices.

Source: 20 years ago, CATV background for 20 years. Ancient history but applicable today.

Comment: Yep - I think crisis is averted. I opened the outlet and sure enough  - there was a 3 way splitter inside it. It is not moca compliant at only 1000 mhz. The splitter sent the cable to another room and one outlet had that cap like you said. So it appears I may be good to go if I can get a moca 2.5 ghz splitter in there?